# Last nonzero digit of $2010!$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial

I have to calculate the last nonzero digit of $2010!$

Till now I couldn't find any pattern.

Comment: [This](http://maths.wordpandit.com/finding-last-non-zero-digit-of-any-factorial/) may be helpful.

Comment: Hint: Every 10th contributes 2 zeros.

Comment: @sloan, I've tried opening your link in two browsers and it show no content beyond the headings. Which is a good illustration of why we try to avoid external links in Math SE. If you can read it, better to summarize the findings for us here in good ol' plain text and MathJax.

Comment: That's the kind of problems I like: where there are no tools at first sight to direct attack of the problem.

Comment: This can be solved using a list of primes and De-Polignac's formula to find out the prime factorization of $2010!$ and then performing arithmetic modulo $10$ but still, the solution will be bashy.

Comment: You have to know the formula below and calculate the x corresponding to 2 and 5. But it is not enough (however necessary I guess) (During consulting the Google traductor the answer of Jack D'Aurizio has appeared, so I omit the formula).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$2010!$ ends with $501$ zeroes since:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{5}\left\lfloor\frac{2010}{5^n}\right\rfloor=501.\tag{1}$$
For the same reason, 
$$ \nu_2(2010!)=\sum_{n=1}^{10}\left\lfloor\frac{2010}{2^n}\right\rfloor=2002\tag{2}$$
so $\frac{2010!}{10^{501}}$ is an even number, and since:
$$ 1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4\equiv -1\pmod{5} \tag{3}$$ 
it follows that:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\frac{2010!}{5^{501}}\equiv \frac{(-1)^{\frac{2010}{5}}5^{402}402!}{5^{501}}&\equiv& \frac{5^{402}\cdot 2 \cdot (-1)^{\frac{400}{5}}\cdot 5^{80}\cdot 80!}{5^{501}}\equiv\frac{5^{482}\cdot 2\cdot 5^{16}\cdot 16!}{5^{501}}\\&\equiv&\frac{2\cdot 16!}{5^3}\equiv\frac{2\cdot(-1)^{\frac{15}{5}}\cdot 5^3\cdot 3!}{5^3}\equiv 3\pmod{5}\end{eqnarray*}$$
and since $2^{501}\equiv 2\pmod{5}$ we have:
$$ \frac{2010!}{10^{501}}\equiv 4\pmod{5}\tag{4} $$
so the last non-zero digit of $2010!$ is $\color{red}{4}$ by the Chinese theorem.

Comment: According to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=last+non-zero+digit+of+2010%21) the last digit is $4$...

Comment: The same with Maple: the last non-zero digit is 4.

Comment: @A.P. and user64494: you were both right, my computation was wrong, but I have fixed it now and it agrees with you.